# AWK output problems

Tags: awk

I wrote a script for getting the MEAN and the STDEV from a data file.
Let's say the data file has this data:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

The awk script looks like this

```
awk '{MEAN+=$1/5}END{print MEAN, STDEV=sqrt(($1-MEAN)**2/4)}' dat.dat>stat1.dat
```

but it gives me an incorrect value of STDEV=1. It must be 1.5811. Do you know what is incorrect in my script? how could I improve it?

Comment: Figure out the correct formula for calculating "stdev" and then write that in awk? Assuming by "stdev" you mean "standard deviation" there's instructions at https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/data-distributions-a1/summarizing-spread-distributions/a/calculating-standard-deviation-step-by-step (google is your friend). hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the same in one pass

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{sum+=$1; sqsum+=$1^2} 
            END{mean=sum/NR; 
                print mean, sqrt((sqsum-NR*mean^2)/(NR-1))}'

3 1.58114
```

note that this is the std definition for "sample population" (divide by N-1).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you(this should work on provided data and if you actual file has more fields too).

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i};mean=sum?sum/NF:0;sum="";for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){$j=($j-mean)*($j-mean);sum+=$j};print "Mean=",mean", S.D=",sqrt(sum/NF)}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){  sum+=$i  };
  mean=sum?sum/NF:0;
  sum="";
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){  $j=($j-mean)*($j-mean);
                       sum+=$j};
                       print "Mean=",mean", S.D=",sqrt(sum/NF)
}
'  Input_file
```

---

***EDIT:*** Adding code similar to above only thing adding exception handling kind of where if any of the value is ZERO it should print 0 then.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){  sum+=$i  };
  mean=sum?sum/NF:0
  sum="";
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){  $j=($j-mean)*($j-mean);
                       sum+=$j};
                       val=sum?sqrt(sum/NF):0
                       print "Mean=",mean", S.D=",val
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the title and tag say `awk`, I wanted to add that calculating the mean and stdev for a column of data can be easily accomplished with [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
seq 1 5 | datamash mean 1 sstdev 1
3   1.5811388300842
```

It may be off-topic here (and I realize that programming simple tasks like that in `awk` can be a good learning opportunity), but I think `datamash` deserves some attention, specially for straightforward calculations such as this one. The documentation gives all the functions it can perform, and good examples as well for files with many columns. It is a fast and reliable alternative. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Wara, please check my answer too specially edit one, it will save you from facing errors too, since I have placed a check for a `0` value. Kindly check it and let me know on same then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two-pass streamable version:

*parse.awk*

```awk
# First-pass:  sum the numbers
FNR == NR { sum += $1; next }

# After first pass:  determine sample size (N) and mean
# Note:  run only once because of the f flag
!f { 
  N    = NR-1    # Number of samples
  mean = sum/N   # The mean of the samples
  f    = 1
}

# Second-pass:  add the squares of the sample distance to mean
{ varsum += ($1 - mean)**2 }

END {
  # Sample standard deviation
  sstd = sqrt( varsum/(N-1) )
  print "Sample std: " sstd
}
```

Run it like this for a file:

```
awk -f parse.awk file.dat{,}
```

Run it like this for streams:

```
awk -f parse.awk <(seq 5) <(seq 5)
```

Output in both cases:

```
Sample std: 1.58114
```